# PHP Escape everything for date function

Tags: php, date, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to escape every single character wrapped in `{{` and `}}` in a string so this:

```
d-m-Y {{warning}}
```

Becomes this:

```
d-m-Y \{\{\w\a\r\n\i\n\g\}\}
```

I'm trying to achieve it using `preg_replace`:

```
$int = preg_match_all('/(\{\{.*?\}\})/', $format, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
if( $int )
{
    $to_replace = preg_replace('/(.+?)/', "\\$1", $matches[0][0]);
    $format = str_replace( $matches[0][0], $to_replace, $format );
}
```

But the replace function converts it to `$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1`, I'm obviously doing something wrong here...

Comment: Seems like you are putting the string straight into `date("d-m-Y \{\{\w\a\r\n\i\n\g\}\}")`. Why not doing `date("d-m-Y")` only and concat the warning ?

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: @rack_nilesh it is `d-m-Y \{\{\w\a\r\n\i\n\g\}\}` as shown in the question

Comment: Because this belongs to a method which accepts a `$format` variable, and the user sets it to describe the output format it wants, after processing it through `date()` I want to replace `{{warning}}` with a dynamic string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `\\$1` should become `\\\$1` in your pattern.

However, you can use `preg_replace_callback()` here:

```
$string = 'd-m-Y {{warning}}';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\{\{.*?\}\}/', function($match) {
    return preg_replace('/./', '\\\$0', $match[0]);
}, $string);
```

Output:

```
d-m-Y \{\{\w\a\r\n\i\n\g\}\}
```

---

During tests, I found out that there is even a faster way to replace the characters in the callback function than `preg_replace()`. You can use `wordwrap()`:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\{\{.*?\}\}/', function($match) {
    return wordwrap($match[0], 1, '\\', true);
}, $string);
```

This will work ~15 % faster than the above attempt.